# Update several properties

Tags: ramda.js

In `ramda` how can I update several properties at once? The closest I could get was using `R.evolve()`. `evolve` wants me to modify a property using a transformation function. I would like to do it directly. However, `R.assoc()` lets me modify only one property at a time and I have to specify the property using a string.

This is how I do it now with `evolve`:

```
const STATE_INITIAL = {
    isDisabled: true,
    isLoading: false
};

R.evolve({
    isDisabled: R.not, 
    isLoading: () => true // I don't want to set a value using a function
    }, state)
```

In JS I would the `object-spread` operator and I would receive a new object:

```
{ ...state, isDisabled: !state.isDisabled, isLoading: true}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use lenses:

```
const isDisabled = R.lensProp('isDisabled');
const isLoading = R.lensProp('isLoading');

//    toggle :: State -> State
const toggle = R.pipe(
  R.over(isDisabled, R.not),
  R.set(isLoading, true)
);

toggle({isDisabled: true, isLoading: false});
// => {isDisabled: false, isLoading: true}
```

See [`R.lensProp`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensProp), [`R.over`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#over), and [`R.set`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#set).

Comment: Interesting option, David. Thank you for sharing it. Quite verbose though. I let the answer unaccepted for now. Maybe somebody will with another solution. If nothing new appears I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ramda tries to keep things simple, so there's not likely a good technique that would allow you to use a function for one property and a value for another, except by piping them through as David Chambers suggests.  His, version, which can also be written like this:

```
const toggle = R.pipe(
  R.over(R.lensProp('isDisabled'), R.not),
  R.set(R.lensProp('isLoading'), true)
)
```

is certainly somewhat more verbose than

```
const toggle = state => {
  ...state,
  isDisabled: !state.isDisabled, 
  isLoading: true    
}
```

But it doesn't seem that bad.  However, if your objection to using functions for both properties is not too strong, there's a variant of your original version with `evolve` that's pretty simple:

```
const toggle = R.evolve({
  isDisabled: R.not, 
  isLoading: R.T
})
```

`R.T` is simply shorthand for `R.always(true)`

Comment: Scott, thanks for your opinion. `R.evolve` seems pretty good to me when it's backed by `R.T` and `R.F`.